# Request for wsTestService.asmx/jsdebug returns 500 error on server, fine in development

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, javascript-debugger

Folks,

I have a simple test application in which I return a string from a web service without arguments.

This works fine under my development environment (VS 2010 SP1Rel on Windows 7 64 bit).

When I deploy to the local IIS7 the proxy code for the web service does not load (in IIS logs it is a 500 error).

When I request the offending url (http://localhost/Tests/WebServiceTests/TestWebServiceProxy/wsTestService.asmx/jsdebug), I get

```
System.InvalidOperationException: jsdebug Web Service method name is not valid.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Brett

Comment: What happens when you load http://localhost/Tests/WebServiceTests/TestWebServiceProxy/wsTestService.asmx in a browser? What about http://localhost/Tests/WebServiceTests/TestWebServiceProxy/wsTestService.asmx?wsdl

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay,

I found the answer.  Somehow I only had a partial install of asp.net 4.0 in IIS7.  I reran

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i`

and now all is well!

Comment: Thanks, for this.  Was having the exact same issues myself.  Fixed it by running aspnet_regiis -1.

Comment: You are welcome!  It is nice to know that someone found this useful.